# Migration Assistant not working

Tags: macbook-pro, migration-assistant, target-disk-mode

I have two M1 MacBook Pros running 14.2.1. I am trying to transfer the data from one computer to the other using **Migration Assistant**.

I have tried connecting via the wireless network. I have tried using a 10GB USB-C cable and no matter what order I try to do this in neither one of the computers recognizes the other and I am not able to transfer the data.

I have also tried doing Target Disk mode, with hopes I could just copy the files over and it does not work. I hold down the T key and boot up. It simply goes to the login screen.

I am not sure what I am missing but I know that I am not succeeding. I welcome guidance.

**Updated:**
One thing that does work is if I connect a Time Machine. That is recognized and allows me to move forward.

Comment: You are following the guide in https://support.apple.com/en-us/102613, I assume? At which step does it fail?

Comment: It fails when I get to the stage where the other Mac is supposed to show up. I get the spinning loader and nothing ever loads.

Comment: First you must have admin privileges on both. Do you know if the disk have same format

Comment: Apple Silicon Macs don't use T - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlb37e8ca7/14.0/mac/14.0

Comment: I have Admin privileges on both computers. Thanks for the update about T.